# Cannot create zpool, how to get rid of intel raid volume?

Tags: raid, freebsd, intel, zpool

This is a FreeBSD 9.1 amd64 computer. It has 5 disks installed. The ada0 and ada1 disks are used with a hw raid to provide the root filesystem:

```
root@gw:/home/gandalf # ls /dev | grep ada
ada0
ada1
ada2
ada3
ada4
root@gw:/home/gandalf # zpool status
  pool: zroot
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    zroot         ONLINE       0     0     0
      raid/r0s1a  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

I want to create a raidz pool for the remaining disks:

```
root@gw:/home/gandalf # zpool create -f data raidz1 ada2 ada3 ada4
cannot create 'data': one or more devices is currently unavailable
root@gw:/home/gandalf # dmesg | grep ada2
ada2 at ata4 bus 0 scbus6 target 0 lun 0
ada2: <WDC WD20EARS-00MVWB0 51.0AB51> ATA-8 SATA 2.x device
ada2: 300.000MB/s transfers (SATA 2.x, UDMA5, PIO 8192bytes)
ada2: 1907729MB (3907029168 512 byte sectors: 16H 63S/T 16383C)
ada2: Previously was known as ad16
root@gw:/home/gandalf # dmesg | grep ada3
ada3 at ata5 bus 0 scbus7 target 0 lun 0
ada3: <SAMSUNG HD103UJ 1AA01118> ATA-7 SATA 2.x device
ada3: 300.000MB/s transfers (SATA 2.x, UDMA5, PIO 8192bytes)
ada3: 953868MB (1953523055 512 byte sectors: 16H 63S/T 16383C)
ada3: Previously was known as ad18
GEOM_RAID: Intel-fb8732fa: Disk ada3 state changed from NONE to ACTIVE.
GEOM_RAID: Intel-fb8732fa: Subdisk Volume0:0-ada3 state changed from NONE to ACTIVE.
root@gw:/home/gandalf # dmesg | grep ada4
ada4 at ata6 bus 0 scbus8 target 0 lun 0
ada4: <TOSHIBA DT01ACA100 MS2OA750> ATA-8 SATA 3.x device
ada4: 300.000MB/s transfers (SATA 2.x, UDMA5, PIO 8192bytes)
ada4: 953869MB (1953525168 512 byte sectors: 16H 63S/T 16383C)
ada4: Previously was known as ad20
root@gw:/home/gandalf # dmesg | grep GEOM_RAID
```

Aha, so ada3 is already part of another raid volume? Let's see:

```
root@gw:/home/gandalf # dmesg | grep GEOM_RAID
GEOM_RAID: SiI-130628113902: Array SiI-130628113902 created.
GEOM_RAID: SiI-130628113902: Disk ada0 state changed from NONE to ACTIVE.
GEOM_RAID: SiI-130628113902: Subdisk SiI Raid1 Set:1-ada0 state changed from NONE to STALE.
GEOM_RAID: SiI-130628113902: Disk ada1 state changed from NONE to ACTIVE.
GEOM_RAID: SiI-130628113902: Subdisk SiI Raid1 Set:0-ada1 state changed from NONE to STALE.
GEOM_RAID: SiI-130628113902: Array started.
GEOM_RAID: SiI-130628113902: Subdisk SiI Raid1 Set:0-ada1 state changed from STALE to ACTIVE.
GEOM_RAID: SiI-130628113902: Subdisk SiI Raid1 Set:1-ada0 state changed from STALE to RESYNC.
GEOM_RAID: SiI-130628113902: Subdisk SiI Raid1 Set:1-ada0 rebuild start at 0.
GEOM_RAID: SiI-130628113902: Volume SiI Raid1 Set state changed from STARTING to SUBOPTIMAL.
GEOM_RAID: SiI-130628113902: Provider raid/r0 for volume SiI Raid1 Set created.
GEOM_RAID: Intel-fb8732fa: Array Intel-fb8732fa created.
GEOM_RAID: Intel-fb8732fa: Force array start due to timeout.
GEOM_RAID: Intel-fb8732fa: Disk ada3 state changed from NONE to ACTIVE.
GEOM_RAID: Intel-fb8732fa: Subdisk Volume0:0-ada3 state changed from NONE to ACTIVE.
GEOM_RAID: Intel-fb8732fa: Array started.
GEOM_RAID: Intel-fb8732fa: Volume Volume0 state changed from STARTING to DEGRADED.
GEOM_RAID: Intel-fb8732fa: Provider raid/r1 for volume Volume0 created.
root@gw:/home/gandalf #
```

Yes, indeed. I want to get rid of raid/r1 completely. However, the controller was already set to "IDE" mode in the BIOS. So why it is creating a raid volume??? I have also tried overwritting the first 16k data of ada3 and reboot the computer, but it did not help.

How can I delete /dev/raid/r1 ?

```
root@gw:/home/gandalf # graid status
   Name      Status  Components
raid/r0  SUBOPTIMAL  ada0 (ACTIVE (RESYNC 4%))
                     ada1 (ACTIVE (ACTIVE))
raid/r1    DEGRADED  ada3 (ACTIVE (ACTIVE))
root@gw:/home/gandalf # graid delete raid/r1
graid: Array 'raid/r1' not found.
root@gw:/home/gandalf # graid delete /dev/raid/r1
graid: Array '/dev/raid/r1' not found.
root@gw:/home/gandalf #
```

Thanks

Comment: removing with graid doesnt work either

Comment: Also tried to use the metadata name (Intel), the volume label (Volume0), the volume name (raid/r1 and r1) in various combinations. It keeps saying that the array is not found. At the same time, it lists the array with "raid/r1" as its name. I'm very confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This not a perfect answer but here is what I did. I turned back the RAID function of the controller in the BIOS. Then I restarted the computer, and went into the BIOS of the RAID card. It showed the disk that was part of a mirror, but was not functional. (I don't know how this happened because that disk was never part of a mirror.) There I have deleted the disk. Then restarted the computer again, set BIOS from RAID to AHCI. Then restarted again. And voila! FreeBSD now could use them as simple disks, and the zpool creation went fine.

The moral of the story: it doesn't matter what you do in the BIOS. FreeBSD+graid will still recognize and use your RAID arrays, even if they are not functional. The real question: why was I not able to delete the raid/r1 volume with graid - I don't know the answer to that. But my workaround solution works (the only problem is that you have to restart the computer serveral times).

Answer (score 3):

(I know you already solved your issue, but I found this when looking for an answer to my own which I solved another way)

I had an issue similar to this (in that GRAID was messing with my system) when I upgraded FreeBSD with an existing ZFS pool.

The pool then became degraded and I received the same sort of DMESG messages you received about an array being built by GEOM_RAID.

My solution was to use 'graid stop' and the name provided as the subdisk name (in your case that would have been 'Volume0'.

The name of the array itself (Intel-fb8732fa in your case) would likely have also worked.

You would also however need to make sure that GRAID was then unloaded from your kernel (or as a module) so that it wouldn't run on every boot and do the same thing.

(the array did re-initialise the next boot, but I managed to prevent it by using graid delete once it had come back up as I hadn't disabled graid entirely)